# Components appelation

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design, components

I found a component in a circuit called DNP0603, I have searched in the net and I did not find an explanation to that, does any one knows what it stands for ??

Comment: Use the search tab above to find existing answers [Why put unpopulated components on a BOM?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/313930/why-put-unpopulated-components-on-a-bom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an 0603 -- probably 0.06 x 0.03" (same as metric 1608 (1.6 x 0.8mm)) part that is not supposed to be populated (DNP).

DNP (Do Not Populate) is an indicator for the BOM (Bill of Materials) and assembly folks that the footprint is to be left open.

Comment: For complete clarity: DNP = Do Not Populate. That is, leave it out.

Comment: Do you mean that the designer does not want to share the this component as a professional secret ?

Comment: not a secret but a variation of the general design, so not needed

Comment: It may not be a professional secret, they just may not know (for example, for a capacitor that may or may not be required for stability). Sometimes SOT (Select On Test) is used for that. Another issue is that if a part number shows up in the BOM sure as anything some purchasing guy is going to order it and it might end up populated, then you have to take them all off.